# No sound Xubuntu 16.04, nothing works

Tags: xubuntu

My sound in Xubuntu is not working. I tried doing

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

which did not fix it. Then I uninstalled and reinstalled pavucontrol, nothing. How do I fix it?

then

```
aplay -l

    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC233 Analog [ALC233 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Here is the output from pacmd list-cards:

https://pastebin.com/7YQYrjBp

The sound stopped working when I pressed pulseaudio -k. 
Now it will not work anymore. Do I need to reinstall xubuntu?

When doing `pulseaudio` I get

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

Comment: `pulseaudio -k` means to kill a running pulseaudio daemon. Did you restart/relogin?

Comment: yes I did `pulseaudio --start` , did a reboot and nothing